# Pushing offline viewable content to iPads for Enterprise

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management, network, documentation

We have rolled out a small deployment of iPads to our Enterprise using iPCU and with a little sweat I'd say we were pretty successful. Our company is pretty large and our demand for iOS solutions is growing. We're currently under a trial license with McAfee EMM (MDM), so we're still getting our feet wet with that.

This has naturally generated a lot of questions from our customers, so we'd like to find a solution to push a How-To document to these devices that pertains to our Enterprise. **Has anyone found a solution for distributing documents to iOS devices that is viewable offline, without having the user to perform many steps?** In a perfect world, we would be able to push a document/app to them w/o any intervention... however this goes against what I know about mobile distribution. The user must manually go into our MDM and download the app. Now I'm looking for the next best solution. Here's how I imagine it working... or other methods I've read:

1) Pushing a Web Clip to the device using a .mobileconfig on initial provisioning (not tested yet). The web clip points to an outward facing site where they grab a PDF. The PDF can then be saved to iBooks for offline viewing. The bad: They're not notified when we make a change to the doc. Or they forget to save the doc to iBooks. Or they don't download iBooks.

2) Develop an Enterprise App with all the content self contained. Contact users via email that the App is available in the Enterprise Store. Any updates to the app are presented as a badge... life is good. The bad: Developer is recompiling and redistributing on every change to the document. Or they don't bother to download the app, when they need it ... it's too late.

3) Drop box - Post the document through drop box for them to grab. The bad: Same as #1

4) Email everyone the doc or post to a website and fend for yourself. This just wont work in our organization.

I know I'm not the only one facing this problem. **The key here is: the least amount of effort for the user, the better.** Right now option #2 seems like the best solution, I'm just curious to see how others have solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: The other "bad" I see with #1 is the webclip can be mistaken as a real app that users think is viewable offline, then never bother saving the document to their device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) shared folders and [Dropbox for teams](https://www.dropbox.com/teams) sounds like it would fulfill your needs.

Comment: I didn't know about Dropbox "Favorites" will save for off-line viewing and will sync when online. That makes things pretty easy on us.